# Why cant my Azure App Service connect to Azure Storage Account with managed identity?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I have a App Service with a managed identity assigned to it to simplify connections to azure resources. I want to use DataProtection where the app stores the xml-keys in an Azure Storage Account(blob) to persist them between deploys.

Whenever I start the app I get a authentication error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<ExecuteSync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.RunWithoutSynchronizationContext[T](Func`1 actionToRun)
```

I have assigned several different RBAC roles to the App Service without any succes, including:

Storage Data Owner
Storage Data Contributor
Storage Data Reader
Owner

The Storage Account is connected to a VNET and not open to the internet. THe App service is not connected to the same VNET.

I have then tried to whitelist the App services many outgoing IP-adresses in the Storage Accounts Network-section, which states "Add IP ranges to allow access from the internet or your on-premises networks."

Also have "Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account" activated.

Any ideas whats missing? This is happening only when in the app service, from my debug-localhost I can connect, so seems related to azure networking somehow.

Comment: It would help if you supplied the code you were using to get the Azure Credentials and whether this issue happens locally, in the cloud, or both. Also a list of the roles that you have tried to assign the App Service's managed identity against the Storage Account.

Comment: If the App Service is connected to one VNET and the Storage account is connected to another VNET, how do you expect to access storage from the app?

Comment: For storages and webapps in the same region, the ip whitelisting won't work as the connection is done through azure internal network rather than public network

Comment: Which role your assgined? According to the existing error message, if it is not the cause of the network, it is likely that there is a problem with the role of the role. Please change to owner or contributor and try again.

Comment: I have updated with more details! It works in local debug to connect if I whitelist my IP in the Storage account. But in production/staging it wont connect.

Comment: Is your local pc connected to the intranet through vpn?

Answer (score 0):

According to the description in your post, I can be pretty sure that your identity configuration in the portal is correct, and your code is also completely correct.

The only problem is that your app services cannot access vnet. The simple description is that the azure storage account is connected to the vnet, which is equivalent to being isolated by the vnet protection. The app service needs to access the storage account, and it must first connect to the vnet.